# Servlet doGet Method getting called multiple times for the same HTTP request

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, seam, lifecycle

I have run into a weird problem. My servlet's doGet method is getting called multiple times for a single HTTP request. The rerun happens every 10-12 seconds till the initial process completes.

Below is my servlet code

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = WebServiceServlet.class.getCanonicalName().hashCode();

private ServletContext servletContext;
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {
    super.init(servletConfig);
    servletContext = servletConfig.getServletContext();
}
/*public WebServiceServlet() {
    super();
}*/
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String output = null;
    /*
     * Calling the Operation Manager which will decide the operation type
     * and call the corresponding operation binder and set the return
     * response generated in http response.
     */
    // Request Processing
    response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print(output);
    out.close();
}
@Override
public void destroy() {
    super.destroy();
}
```

Below is the mapping in the web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>WebServiceServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>WebServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.servlet.WebServiceServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WebServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/web.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I am using SEAM and JSF but this is a standalone servlet. There is no exception in the logs. I have also verified that the INIT method is being called only once. It is the service method which is being repeated. The identity hash code comes same for all the reruns (System.identityHashCode(this)).

The call is being made from a REST API tester. There are no multiple calls happening from the caller. The reruns are happening over the tomcat container.

I am at my wit's end. Has anyone else faced this issue?

Comment: Who's the caller?, a page in the browser?, have you checked with Firebug or Developer tools how many calls are happening?

Comment: Generally you would not override the service method, but only use doPost, doGet, etc which service calls. Are these methods also being called multiple times?

Comment: To understand why the service is called you need to understand the servlet life cycle, and how the container works. The service might be called to poll, might be called from other doXXXX methods that has nothing to do from your solution implementation. You can make a more verbose output to see what is going on. For the rest, see my answer below.

Comment: I had overridden the service method to simply test the reruns. The reruns are happening even without overriding the service method.

Also, I have tested the API call from the browser. It is only happening once. The reruns are happening in the container.

Comment: Can you share some more details . From where is this servlet called.

Comment: @JafarAli, the servlet is called from the browser through a Angular Service. But when I noticed the problem, I tested the URL from REST API client also but with the same result. The reruns are not happening from the caller. They are happening over the tomcat server.

Comment: @AkhileshAggarwal please try to be clear when editing the question, it makes confusion. And can you please run the tests again and apply outputs for both doGet and doPost and see if they match your output (timestamp etc) from service() method too. You need to localize the service types/methods to dispatch. And what other 3rd party libraries do you use ? what tomcat version? jvm?

Comment: @MrSimpleMind I am sorry if my question caused confusion. I have done the testing again on doGet and doPost and the time stamp and the identity hash code are coming same.

Basically, in the servlet lifecycle, service method calls the doGet or doPost method. So the question earlier was based on that. Now also, the question is same, I have simply edited it to doGet method as it was causing confusion.

Comment: @AkhileshAggarwal what tomcat version do you run ?

Comment: @MrSimpleMind I am using Tomcat 7 and Sun JDK 7.

Comment: Is it really the doGet that get executed? earlier you said service() method, can you confirm. And do you manually manipulate any headers? (do you any setHeader(...) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83281/discussion-between-akhilesh-aggarwal-and-mrsimplemind).

Comment: What does  *the rerun happens every 10-12 seconds till the initial process completes.* actually mean. What is the initial process?

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue.

Just keep the `@post` method in your servlet class. Comment out `@get` and `@put` if you have.

Thanks